# Declaring a variable from a string input (Java)

Tags: java

When I previously asked a question, it got many downvotes because I was not very specific. I will do my best to be clear this time. I have read questions with similar titles, but none have made it clear to me.

Basically, I have been assigned to make a fractional calculator for my AP comp sci class. The first checkpoint for this assignment is to be able to read fractions inputted by the user without the code crashing. For example, "1_1/2" "1/2" or just 1.

So far, I've gotten the following -

```
public static void identify() {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        String fraction = console.next();

        if(fraction.contains("_")) {
            int wholenumber = console.nextInt();
            int numerator = console.nextInt();
            int denomenator = console.nextInt();
            System.out.print(wholenumber + "_" + numerator + "/" + denomenator);
        }
        else if(fraction.contains("/")) {
            int numerator = console.nextInt();
            int denomenator = console.nextInt();
            System.out.print(numerator + "/" + denomenator);

        } 
        else {                                                                          
            System.out.print(fraction);
        }

        }
```

I thought it was working at first, but then I realized that if I inputted 1_1/2 or 1/2, the code would wait for inputs for the numerator, denominator, and whole number. So my problem is that I want the previously mentioned values to be declared from the originally inputted string, and not from different inputs.

I understand this might be confusing to read, so basically
I if input 1_1/2, I want my code to declare 1 as wholenumber, 1 as numerator, and 2 as denominator. How would I achieve this?

Comment: [Find all numbers in the String](//stackoverflow.com/q/13440506)

Comment: @Tom What do you mean?

Comment: Define a pattern for scanning input data.

Comment: @RomanC Im sorry I do not understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int[] numbers = Arrays.asList(fraction.split("_|/")).stream()
            .mapToInt(s -> Integer.parseInt(s))
            .toArray();
```

Then, 
If entry is of type `1_1/2` :

- wholenumber = numbers[0]
- numerator = numbers[1]
- denomenator = numbers[2]

If entry is of type `1/2` :

- numerator = numbers[0]
- denomenator = numbers[1]

Comment: sorry, still new to this. Just did I think

Comment: yep, you can upvote as well if you liked it but thats up to you. Basically its just meant to tell people with similar questions that this answer could resolve their problem.

Comment: yes I upvoted as well but it does not count because I don’t have enough reputation. Thank you for the help though!